# Disable anchor preview on iPad running iOS 11

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-safari, ios11

I am having an issue when trying to code a long press image change on iOS 11, specifically iPad devices whereby I cannot seem to stop the anchor preview from displaying. This affects the animation from running properly as displays the image with a box shadow. If I completely remove the anchor tag then this works as expected. This preview functionality does not happen on an iPhone running iOS11.

I have tried using e.preventDefault to prevent mobile Safari and Chrome on the iPad from performing this action by default but it does not seem to resolve it.

The only option I can think of is to remove the anchor tag and use window.location.href on a click of the containing parent but this is not desirable. Has anyone else come across this issue before?

```js
$('body')
.on('touchend', frameContainerIdSelector, function(e) {
        if (e.type === 'touchend') {
          if (isScrolling) {
            clearTimeouts();
            isScrolling = false;
            return false;
          }
          clearTimeouts();
          if (longPress === true) {
            e.preventDefault();
            longPress = false;
          }
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
          hoverOutFrame($(this));
        }
      })
      .on('touchstart', frameContainerIdSelector, function(e) {
        var self = $(this);
        if (e.type === 'touchstart') {
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
          clearTimeouts();
          if (!isScrolling) {
            pressTimer = setTimeout(function() {
              longPress = true;
              hoverInFrame(self);
            }, framePressDelay);
          }
        }
      })
      .on('touchforcechange', frameContainerIdSelector, function(event) { //disables 3D touch on ios devices
        var force = event.changedTouches[0].force;

        if (force > 0.1) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .on('contextmenu', frameContainerIdSelector, function() { if (isTouchDevice()) return false; }); // stops default android menus
```

The above shows the code I am using to trigger a long press on the container and the hover in/hover out functions just lazy load a new image and then animate accordingly.

UPDATE
I have now managed to get rid of the ugly border around the image by setting pointer-events: none on the image. However mobile Safari running iOS version 11.4.1 still insists on adding something to the touchstart when a long touch is applied. See below.

[image: iPad touch start issue]

I believe this is something to do with 3D touch but what is confusing about this is that an iPhone 6S running the same iOS version does not do this with 3D Touch switched on! Is this something that can be solved by code? I have tried adding user-select: none and -webkit-touch-callout: none but still to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by using:

```css
a {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

This essentially disables dragging on the device so treated it as a draggable element.